# Calculate number of possible operands

Tags: javascript

I need a function to calculate the number of possible addition equations for a given sum n.

The operands must always be in descending order, cannot be equal, and must be greater than 0.

So, 5+4 is valid but 4+5 5+5 3+3+3 or 9+0 are not.  Only integers are used.

For instance:

n = 2. Result is 0

n = 3. Result is 1. 2+1

n = 5.  Result is 2. 4+1 and 3+2

n = 10. Result is 8.  9+1, 8+2, 7+3, 6+4, 7+2+1, 6+3+1, 5+4+1, 5+3+2

Comment: You may want to specify some more rules. Is 5+0 valid? 0.1+4.9? 6 + (-1)?

Comment: n = 2. result should be 1: 1+1

Comment: Operands cannot be equal, 1+1 is not valid.

Comment: function calc(){}

Comment: is it count(10) = 9, you miss the case 4+3+2+1

Answer (score 1):

Just divide the number by 2 and floor the result:

```js
function calc(num){
  return Math.floor(num/2);
} 

console.log(calc(5)) //4+1, 2+3
console.log(calc(6)) //1+5, 2+4, 3+3
console.log(calc(7)) //1+6, 2+5, 3+4
```

Comment: This does not work... calc(10) should be 8, not 5

Comment: @JosephTroy It did work prior to OP's edit (and change in requirements).